# using Oracle instead of SQL Server in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Here instead of `SqlHelper` I need to execute it through Oracle. Is there anything like `OracleHelper` for C#? If so how can I use it here

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle;
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;

  public DataSet GetAsdDollarsaleschangeList(String requestId,String reportCode )
  {
  try
  {
  OracleDatabase db = new OracleDatabase("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=***)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME= ***)));User Id= ***;Password= ***;Persist Security Info=True;");
  OracleParameter[] _spParams = new OracleParameter[1];
  _spParams[0] = new OracleParameter(ReportCode.requestId,requestId);
  return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(db, CommandType.StoredProcedure, ReportCode.PEP_1, _spParams);
  }
  catch (Exception err)
  {
  throw err;
  }
  }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend downloading and installing [ODP.Net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html). I would also recommend studying the code samples they have [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/dotnet-sample-522126.html), which should get you going.